# WinRT event not returning EventRegistrationToken

Tags: c#, dynamic, windows-runtime, event-handling, windows-store-apps

I am hoping someone can help me this problem... or can clarify what I am doing wrong...
I am dynamically adding event handlers to an event. 
This works very well for Controls that comes with XAML, but not for my own events. I found out that in WinRT events returns a EventRegistrationToken. According to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972883(v=vs.110).aspx) "add" should return a token.
My problem is that all events that I implement only returns void.
I created multiple projects (Win 8 WinRT, Win 8.1 Universal, Win 10 Universal) already to find out what I am doing wrong. Every project are showing the same problem. 
I googled hours... and every implementation I found are stating that "add" requires a return object.

My questions are:

1. Do someone know if this is a bug?
2. If not a bug... Is there something I have to set or change so that my events are returning a token?
3. If events are behaving like they should on your environment, can you please provide me with a test project so that I can so a compare. Maybe this has something to do with project settings or type.

edit: finally I can add an image...
[image: This is what I mean]

PS: I also posted my code for the dynamic event handling on pastebin [(code of DynamicEventHandler)](http://pastebin.com/hdukGK0U)

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

var method = this.GetType().GetRuntimeMethods().First(x => x.Name == "ExecuteCommand")

The ExecuteCommand is a .NET method rather than the Windows Runtime method, why do you use "GetRuntimeMethods"?

Here is the code works on my side.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var runtimeEvent = this.myButton.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent("Click");
    var handlerMethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("OnClick");

    var delegateHandler = handlerMethodInfo.CreateDelegate(runtimeEvent.EventHandlerType, this);

    Func<Delegate, EventRegistrationToken> add = (a) => {
        return (EventRegistrationToken)runtimeEvent.AddMethod.Invoke(this.myButton, new object[] { a });
    };

    Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove = (a) => { runtimeEvent.RemoveMethod.Invoke(runtimeEvent, new object[] { a }); };

    WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler(add, remove, delegateHandler);
}

public void OnClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```